# Binding datagrid cell background color

Tags: c#, wpf

I am binding datagrid cell background color like this and binding is working.

```
<DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="50" Header="Count" Binding="{Binding ItemCount}" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserSort="False">
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Color}"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

But when I bind it like this, it changes text block's background color, not entire cell. Let's say if my item count is over 100, there is no problem. Text block covers whole cell. But if it is less than 100, you can see cell's background because text block can't cover whole cell.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: there is `DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle` for DataGridCell elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `CellStyle` to set the background for the cells:

```
<DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="50" Header="Count" Binding="{Binding ItemCount}" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserSort="False">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Color}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: I've totally forgot CellStyle @mm8 Thank you so much!